# Javascript convert string to object?

Tags: javascript, json

Not sure what to write as a title, but this is my problem:

```
  if(selectedCountry=="India"){
    stateArray=[]
    Object.keys(jsonObj.India).forEach(function(k) {
      stateArray.push(k)
    });
  }

  if(selectedCountry=="USA"){
    stateArray=[]
    Object.keys(jsonObj.USA).forEach(function(k) {
      stateArray.push(k)
    });
  }
  if(selectedCountry=="UK"){
    stateArray=[]
    Object.keys(jsonObj.UK).forEach(function(k) {
      stateArray.push(k)
    });
  }
  if(selectedCountry=="none"){
    stateArray=[]
  }
  for (var i=0; i<stateArray.length; i++){
    var stateOption = new Option(stateArray[i],stateArray[i])
    if (states.length<stateArray.length+1){
      states.appendChild(stateOption);

    }
```

Although the code is working, it is bad way of doing it. Is there a way where I rewrite the code so I don't need the if statements? Because selected country is a string, I cannot use:

```
 Object.keys(jsonObj.selectedCountry).forEach(function(k) {
      stateArray.push(k)
    });
```

Is there any way around it? Thx

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `stateArray = Object.keys(jsonObj[selectedCountry] || {});`

Answer (score 0):

Two factors:

1. Reduce duplication; for all eventualities, `stateArray` begins as an empty array, so declare that once. If country is none, it remains just an empty array.
2. To reference a key/property dynamically, use square-bracket syntax rather than dots

   ```
   stateArray = [];
   if(selectedCountry !== "none")
       Object.keys(jsonObj[selectedCountry]).forEach(function(k) {
           stateArray.push(k)
       });
   ```

Comment: There's absolutely no need to use `.forEach` and `.push` here - the desired array _is_ the `Object.keys`

Comment: Well I just carried that across from the question, since it was not the focus of the question, which was, rather, how to omit the conditionals and how to reference dynamic properties.

Comment: Sure, but why use 5 lines when one will do  (and avoiding the repeated function callbacks in the process) ?

Answer (score 0):

This would be the correct approach. There is no reason to create an array then create the options. Simply create the options as you read the object's keys.

```js
var geographicalData = getGeoData();
var countrySelect = document.getElementById('country');

populateCombo(countrySelect, geographicalData);

countrySelect.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var stateSelect = document.getElementById('state');
  stateSelect.options.length = 0;                       // Empty values.
  var selectedCountry = e.target.value;
  
  if (geographicalData[selectedCountry]) {
    populateCombo(stateSelect, geographicalData[selectedCountry]);
  }
});

countrySelect.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change')); // Trigger change.

function populateCombo(combo, obj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj).sort();
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var option = new Option(keys[i], keys[i]);
    combo.appendChild(option);
  }
}

function getGeoData() {
  return {
    "India" : {
      "Maharashtra" : 1,
      "Tamil Nadu" : 1,
      "Uttar Pradesh" : 1,
      "West Bengal" : 1,
      "Gujarat" : 1,
      "Karnataka" : 1,
      "Rajasthan" : 1,
      "Andhra Pradesh" : 1,
      "Madhya Pradesh" : 1,
      "Delhi" : 1
    },
    "USA" : {
      "California" : 1,
      "Florida" : 1,
      "New York" : 1,
      "Texas" : 1,
      "Hawaii" : 1,
      "Washington" : 1,
      "Colorado" : 1,
      "Virginia" : 1,
      "North Carolina" : 1,
      "Arizona" : 1
    },
    "UK" : {
      "South West" : 1,
      "East of England" : 1,
      "South East" : 1,
      "East Midlands" : 1,
      "Yorkshire and the Humber" : 1,
      "North West" : 1,
      "West Midlands" : 1,
      "North East" : 1,
      "London" : 1,
      "Scotland" : 1,
      "Wales" : 1,
      "Northern Ireland" : 1
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<select id="country"></select>
<select id="state"></select>
```